# buscar textbox dentro de div

Tags: php, jquery

tengo lo siguiente

```
<div class="d1" id="div1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
</div>
<div class="d1" id="div2">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
</div>
```

lo que quiero hacer es recorrer todos los textbox para poder cambiarles el class a los vacios y tambien el class al div que tenga textbox vacios...

intente esto:

```
   var inputs = $("#div1 > input");

// una vez tenemos el array, podemos iterar 
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   var in = inputs[i].val();
   if (in.length > 0) {
 // no está vacío 
  }
}
```

pero no funciona... algún consejo?

muchas gracias!

Comment: no estoy muy seguro pero creo que es así
var inputs = $("#div1 > input[text]");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estas utilizando todo el arsenal de jQuery.  Puedes validar todos los inputs y su contenedores asi:

```js
function validar() {
  var inputs = $("input");

  $.each(inputs, function(i, input) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).addClass("empty");
      $(this).parent().addClass("empty");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.empty {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1" id="div1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
</div>
<div class="d1" id="div2">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
</div>
<button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Comment: genial camarada! muchas gracias esto si me sirvió... con unas pequeñas modificaciones que le hice pero si me funciono! una pregunta...si solo quisiera que valide unos DIV en especifico? en mi formulario tengo muchos DIV y con el codigo que puse se repasa todos los inputs de mi pagina... gracias!

Comment: Podrias agregar una clase a los divs que quieres validar y solo seleccionar esa clase

Comment: genial!!!! gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo un código de ejemplo, con comentarios en cada línea.

Que te sirva

```js
//Cuando el DOM esté listo
$(function(){
  
  //Hacer algo cuando el botón sea clickeado
  $(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
    
    //Recorrer todos los elementos con clase t1
    $('.t1').each(function(){
        
        //capturar valor
        let val = $(this).val();
        
        //Validar si está vacio o no, trim quita espacios en blanco
        if( !val || val.trim() == '' ){
           //Si está vacio añadir clase
           $(this).addClass('sin-valor');
           $(this).removeClass('con-valor');
        }
        
        else{
          //Si no está vacio añadir otra clase
           $(this).addClass('con-valor');
           $(this).removeClass('sin-valor');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.con-valor{
  background-color: green;
}

.sin-valor{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d1" id="div1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
</div>
<div class="d1" id="div2">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
 <input type="text" class="t1">
</div>

<button id="btn">Valorar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner `Ids` para identificar cada `input`, y pon esto en tu **JavaScript**:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {

var inp;
$('#div1 > input').each(function() {
   inp = $(this).val();
   if (inp.length > 0) {
       console.log( $(this).attr("id") + 'no esta vacio' );
  }
});
})(window, document, window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usando Jquery** 
-   Para cambiar la clase puedes usar la función toggleClass, con esta eliminas los css que coincidan con los actuales y adicionas los que no estén.
En este caso si quieres eliminar t1 y agregar t2 seria toggleClass('t1 t2');
-   Para seleccionar los elementos vacíos usa la función filter, aplicándola a todos los inputs y seleccionando los que cumplan con la condición val == false, si encuentras uno que cumpla la condición que val sea vació, le cambias la clase al elemento y a su padre.

Combinando esto seria

```
$(":input").filter(function () {  
      return !this.value; 
}).toggleClass('t1 t2').parent('div').toggleClass('d1 d2');**
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y da click al icono que es una hoja con un simbolo "<>" en medio luego dentro de las comillas que coloque en la descripción de tu pregunta pega tu código de esta forma le das formato y queda legible. Un saludo